# Multithread download on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I need to download a file on my website, and this file is too big. So need to dowload it by multithreading method.

How can i use it with WebClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backgroundworker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Setup the background worker like on the msdn page
and in the event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            // Download your file here
        }
```

Comment: can you give me some examples?